# MYSQL: SELECT or DELETE, which is better in terms of performance to avoid duplication

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table with millions of records. I have to make sure records are unique. I wonder whether a `SELECT.. where` is better or `DELETE..where`?

Question Update: I want to keep only UNIQUE RECORDS.

**Further update**

I am running threads and for some unknown reasons they are inserting dups in tabke despite of checking... most probably due to simultaneous running of SELECT. So asking that if checking of record existence is costlier than simply deleting rows matching records?

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Do you just want to show the Unique records or Do you want to store only unique records?

Comment: Or do you simply want a yes/no about whether they are all unique?  There are answers to all the possible questions; I don't want to launch into answering the wrong question.

Comment: @RickJames I am running threads and for some unknown reasons they are inserting dups in tabke despite of checking... most probably due to simultaneous running of `SELECT`. So asking that if checking of record existance is costlier than simply deleting rows matching records?

Comment: Checking of existence won't work if not in transaction.  Look into `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: @RickJames But I don't have to update.

Comment: Please answer _two_ questions.  Do you need to eliminate the existing dups, yes or no?  Do you need to prevent new dups, yes or no?

Comment: @RickJames The real objective is to *No DUPS* - Now whether `SELECT` is better or `DELETE` for a table with millions of records, I am asking that.

Comment: So, you have 2 questions?  (1) "How do I get rid of the dups that exist?", and (2) "How do I prevent dups in the future?"

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT IGNORE` to avoid errors about duplicate keys when accidentally inserting the same record twice.

Note:  That only checks any `UNIQUE` keys (including the `PRIMARY KEY, if specified.)

But...  That points out that you _do not have a `UNIQUE` key to prevent duplicates in the first place!

So, your next question will be how to add a `UNIQUE` key when there are already duplicates.  Correct.

Trying to discover the duplicates and delete them is complex and tedious, but possibly faster.

This is straightforward:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
ALTER TABLE new ADD UNIQUE ... -- some UNIQUE KEY to avoid duplicates
# stop writes to `real`  -- application-specific
INSERT IGNORE INTO new SELECT * FROM real;
RENAME TABLE real TO old,
             new TO real;
# allow writes again.
DROP TABLE old;
```

Comment: I have `ID` field which is `AUTO INCREMENT`, the duplicate field is the `URL` field.